# Unexpected Behaviour on StringTokenizer

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I have this input string:

```
21. Sponge Cake by Charlie Montoya [2014-10-13]
```

And I am attempting to parse the string to extract information from it, i.e. :

id = "21";
title = "Sponge Cake";
author = "Charlie Montoya";
date = "2014-10-13";

I am using StringTokenizer:

```
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
    System.out.println("id? : "+ tokenizer.nextToken(".").trim());
    System.out.println("title? : "+ tokenizer.nextToken("by").trim());
    System.out.println("author? : "+tokenizer.nextToken().trim());
    System.out.println("date? : "+tokenizer.nextToken("[").trim());
```

my output is:

```
    id? : 21
    title? : . Sponge Cake
    author? : Charlie Monto
    date? : ya
```

There are various things wrong here:
The title is preceded by the "." which should have been the delimiter after the id.
The final 2 characters of the author's name appear instead on the date field
The actual date is missing.

How can I correct these problems?

Comment: `StringTokenizer` is sort of outdated. I recommend using `Scanner` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The delimiters arn't consumed by the tokenizer and when you change the delimiter it is part of the next token.
This should solve it:

```
System.out.println("id? : " + tokenizer.nextToken(".").trim());
tokenizer.nextToken(" ");
System.out.println("title? : " + tokenizer.nextToken("by").trim());
tokenizer.nextToken(" ");
System.out.println("author? : " + tokenizer.nextToken("[").trim());
System.out.println("date? : " + tokenizer.nextToken("[]").trim());
```

I also would recommend using the Scanner class, like Sweeper already did.